# Fortnite ping icon in top left

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

A ping icon is on the top left of my screen with "kbs" and it is really annoying. I have checked in the settings and can't find an option that removes it. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have any pictures of it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this. Epic made an update recently so it stuck there. Unfortunately, we all seem to be stuck with the packet loss signs in the corner.